# Unable to set access policy to key vault for an application in Azure CLI

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

In the [docs for policy management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal), they show how to assign an application to be allowed as a principal to access the key vault. I'd like to do that using Azure CLI.

For a user, I [figured out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net?tabs=azure-cli#grant-access-to-your-key-vault) that I should execute the following.

```
az keyvault set-policy --name kv-holder --upn my.email@here.onmicrosoft.com --secret-permissions all
```

However, doing the corresponding thing for a registered service doesn't work. I can do that in the GUI, specifying the application as a principal (step 2, not 3!) as illustrated in the item 4 at in the docs. But doing any of the following, seems to fail.

```
az keyvault set-policy --name kv-holder --upn app-web-service --secret-permissions all
az keyvault set-policy --name kv-holder --spn app-web-service --secret-permissions all
az keyvault set-policy --name kv-holder --object-id app-web-service --secret-permissions all
az keyvault set-policy --name kv-holder --application-id app-web-service --secret-permissions all
```

I get errors barking at me that precisely one of *upn*, *spn* or *object-id* must be specified and when I do, it tells me there's no user by that name.

What am I missing? And where did they hide info on how to do this programmatically, not from the portal?

When I tried `object-id` and the GUID of the application, it seemed to accept the request. However, in the GUI I now see a section named *Unknown* (below the previously created section named *Application*) and my GUID is listed there while the application (referring to the same GUID!) is listed separately in the other section. They do have different set of privileges, which confuses me even more...

Comment: it can be a bit confusing with all the IDs, there is also a concept of Enterprise vs App registration and in my code I used ID's from both, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/one-dev-minute/difference-between-app-registration-and-enterprise-apps-in-azure-ad

 also, do use an app registration and its "credentials file" , and not your own "email" .   However, I am not an expert in this area.

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten, you need to pass `objectID` of **service principal** not the application. You can find that **service principal** in Enterprise applications of your Azure AD tenant with same name as application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set access policy to key vault for an **application** in Azure CLI, you
can make use of below command:

```
az keyvault set-policy --name <kvname> --object-id <service_principal_ID> --secret-permissions all
```

I created one Azure AD application with same name as you like below:

[image]

If you pass above **Application ID** or **Object ID** in **`--object-id`** parameter of CLI command, it will be added as Unknown.

> Note that, you need to pass `objectID` of **service principal** not
> the application.

You can find that **service principal** in Enterprise applications of your Azure AD tenant with same name as application like below:

[image]

When I ran below **CLI command** by including above service principal `ObjectID`, it added in access policy successfully like below:

```
az keyvault set-policy --name <kvname> --object-id <service_principal_ID> --secret-permissions all
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: We may have a problem here. I navigated to the *enterprise applications* and saw a long list of items. When I filtered for mine, it seems it's not there. Do I need to register my web service as an enterprise application? If not, what now?! If so, how do I do that (GUI would be nice but I'd definitely like to do that from Azure CLI in the end, as it give me the sensation of more control)?

Comment: Also, I just noticed the application that I got into *Aplications* section (manually specifying in in the GUI), doesn't show up in the list of enterprise applications, so I'm not entirely sure it's required to be there.

Comment: If you registered application via CLI or powershell, service principal won't be created. So, you cannot find it in Enterprise Applications. In that case, you can manually create it with this command: `az ad sp create --id <appID>`

Comment: Thanks. Few FUQs. (1) Is that operation equivalent to setting the status *On* in the application's *Settings>Identity* section? I'm asking so because once I did that and copied **that** GUID, then the app popped in under *Application* section. Also, (2) what if I want to use the **name** of my web service and not the GUID of it? I can't create a service principal that way. How could I do that?

Comment: When you create an application from Portal, `User.Read` permission is added to it in API permissions that automatically make service principal in Enterprise Applications. But you have to manually create it when you register app via CLI or Powershell which is necessary for authenticating and giving access to Azure resources.

Comment: As mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create), you can only use GUID to create a service principal with CLI command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253650/discussion-between-sridevi-and-konrad-viltersten).

Comment: Yupp. I answered in the chat.

Comment: I lost the track of time and then the chat room got deleted. However, I finally figured it out (and forgot to let you know for a few months, sorry about that).