# How to override, by code, sink properties set by appsettings

Tags: serilog, datadog

My ASP.NET Web Api has appsettings.json specifying Serilog with Serilog.Sinks.Datadog.Logs.
This works fine, however, the arg "apiKey" is specified in clear text which breaks our company standard.
I would like to overwrite that specific property by code (at composition root).
(Something that code has accessed from some secrets manager)
Anyone knows how to do this? (C#)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the API Key inside the code where you create the logger instance. See below sample code.

I have handle such scenario by replacing appsettings.json values with Azure Key vault url. Check out this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68224000/using-keyvault-secrets-to-override-appsettings-in-azure-app-service-and-locally)

> Sample code:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.DatadogLogs("<API_KEY>")
    .CreateLogger();
    
// An example
var position = new { Latitude = 25, Longitude = 134 };
var elapsedMs = 34;

Log.Information("Processed {@Position} in {Elapsed:000} ms.", position, elapsedMs);
Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

For more information check [here](https://github.com/DataDog/serilog-sinks-datadog-logs) for more information.