# How do I access Azure Key Vault Secrets from my ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-keyvault

I am new to Azure and the Azure Key Vault. I've read a number of tutorials about how to setup my Web API to leverage the Azure Key Vault but after successfully storing a secret and setting up my `Program.cs` file with the code below, I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do next to actually access the secret in my classes.

My original goal was to store the connection string for my database in Key Vault, then when the API starts up I would get the connection string and "store" it locally (in memory) to be used by my data access layer classes.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri"));
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint,
    new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

I have a class that inherits from `DbContext` and was expecting to get the secret to set the class's connection string - ideally without going back to the key vault every time and pulling it locally (but not storing it in a file). I'm thinking this is just a gap on my side of how this flow is supposed to work.

Any help to get me on track would be great!

### UPDATE

I can see that `builder.Configuration` does include the secrets I'm after. Now I'm just struggling to get that information to a place that I can access from my DbContext classes without additional calls to Key Vault and without storing them in a local file.

Comment: You need to give your Azure App Service a Managed Service Identity, then grant that Identity read-only access to the minimum set of secrets needed in your Key Vault, then use the Azure Key Vault client lib ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets ) to retrieve the values during `Startup` and keep them in-memory. You **don't want** to retrieve them _every time_ your `DbContext` is instantiated.

Comment: Hi @Dai and thank you for the help! I guess I'm still uncertain on how to retrieve/store the value after the line I shared? For example, after I call "AddAzureKeyVault" what should I do next? An example would be really helpful. I see the link you shared instantiates a new SecretClient but I'm not sure how that fits into what I did with AddAzureKeyVault...

Comment: The documentation is rather thin on this but one way is to use the overload of `AddAzureKeyVault()` that accepts an `IKeyVaultSecretManager` argument. The `DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager` will load all secrets from the key vault and create new `IConfiguration` values for them. In our team we use a custom implementation that checks for config values of the format `${my-secret-name}` and tries to find a secret with the same name in the key vault in order to replace the config placeholder value with the secret value in memory.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68224000/using-keyvault-secrets-to-override-appsettings-in-azure-app-service-and-locally

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride thank you for this. I'm surprised that there is such little documentation for something that MS points to as a best practice again and again. Would it be possible for you to share an example of how you're going about it? I followed the link you provided but I'm still struggling to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to add more about [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#defaultazurecredential).

OP said he already saw the secrets in `builder.Configuration` after `builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());` which is using DefaultAzureCredential to connect to Azure KeyVault like the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources) introduced.

Certainly we can reach the secrets from the built-in configuration property like `builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("property_name")` but we still need to know if we are planning to host the app in Azure app service and wants to use managed identity, then we need to use code below instead.

```
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
       new Uri("https://vaultName.vault.azure.net/"),
       new DefaultAzureCredential(
           new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = "userManagedIdentityClientId" }//required when using user ManagedIdentity
       ));
```

If we don't prefer to use managed identity, or we want to host the app in a VM, then we need to set [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#environment-variables): `AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` to make sure the `DefaultAzureCredential` could also work. Don't forget to update the [access-control policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/best-practices#control-access-to-your-vault) for managed identity or AAD application.

Comment: This help'd me get to the core of my problem. I'm still figuring out DI and the EF. After using your example I was able to piece together DI that I pushed to a basecontroller for which I could set the necessary info to a static class. Not sure if this is best but got me going.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a custom `IKeyVaultSecretManager` to replace secret placeholders in our app settings files with key vault secrets.

A config value of the form `${secret-name}` will be replaced with the value of a key vault secret of the same name. This all happens in memory when the app settings file is loaded into a `IConfiguration` instance.

The custom secret manager:

```cs
namespace Foo;

using Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

internal class KeyVaultSecretReplacer : KeyVaultSecretManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _placeholders;

    public KeyVaultSecretReplacer(IConfiguration config)
        => _placeholders = config
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(HasSecretPlaceholder)
            .ToDictionary(
                keySelector: GetSecretName,
                elementSelector: GetSettingKey,
                StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public override bool Load(SecretProperties secret) => _placeholders.ContainsKey(secret.Name);

    public override Dictionary<string, string> GetData(IEnumerable<KeyVaultSecret> secrets)
    {
        var loadedSecrets = secrets.ToArray();
        ValidateAllSecretsFound(loadedSecrets);
        return base.GetData(loadedSecrets);
    }

    private void ValidateAllSecretsFound(IList<KeyVaultSecret> secrets)
    {
        var missing = _placeholders.Keys.Except(secrets.Select(s => s.Name)).ToArray();

        if (!missing.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var vaultName = secrets.FirstOrDefault()?.Properties.VaultUri.Host.Replace(".vault.azure.net", "");
        var notFoundMsg = string.Join(", ", missing.Select(s => $"'{s}' (setting '{_placeholders[s]}')"));
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            $"Some secrets were not found in key vault{(vaultName is null ? "" : $" '{vaultName}'")}: {notFoundMsg}.");
    }

    public override string GetKey(KeyVaultSecret secret) => _placeholders[secret.Name];

    internal static bool HasSecretPlaceholder(KeyValuePair<string, string?> c)
        => c.Value != null && c.Value.StartsWith("${") && c.Value.EndsWith("}");

    private static string GetSecretName(KeyValuePair<string, string?> c) => c.Value![2..^1];

    private static string GetSettingKey(KeyValuePair<string, string?> c) => c.Key;
}
```

Parts of the usage:

```cs
private static void AddKeyVaultSecretReplacer(IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder, IConfigurationRoot config)
{
    var settings = config.GetSection(nameof(SecretReplacement))?.Get<SecretReplacementSettings>()
        ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Secret placeholders found in app settings but {nameof(SecretReplacement)} has not been configured.");

    configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(
        new Uri(settings.AzureKeyVaultUrl),
        new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { TenantId = settings.AzureTenantId }),
        new KeyVaultSecretReplacer(config));
}
```